# Evaluating fractions in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has 5 columns and 200+ rows, with each cell randomly containing a fraction formatted as a 'x/y' string or a nan value.

I want to turn each fraction into its decimal value. When I try this,

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.eval(x) if pd.notnull(x[0]) else x, axis=1)
```

df turns into an unusable series. Changing the axis to 0 does not work because df.apply cannot process such a large number of rows.

Using df.applymap does not work because it executes twice to test the function, causing a division by zero error.

What is the best solution?

Comment: Try `df.stack().map(lambda x: pd.eval(x) if pd.notna(x) else x)`?

Comment: @cs95 That converts the values correctly but turns df into a stacked series. How do I reformat it back to the original DataFrame of columns and indexes?

Comment: Oh whoops forgot to undo that; add an `unstack` at the end: `result_df = df.stack().map(lambda x: pd.eval(x) if pd.notna(x) else x).unstack()`

Comment: @cs95 the unstack worked but the nan values are lost, the goal was to keep them and the evaluated fractions in their original indexes

Comment: huh, change stack() to stack(dropna=False)

Comment: @cs95 still getting a float division by zero error.

Comment: My code works, just so happens you have `x/y` where `y == 0` :-)

Comment: @cs95 just looked through all the data.... of course there's a 0/0 hidden near the bottom. thanks for your help